# Unknown process overloading cpu - kperl

Tags: process

I am not a Linux expert.
I noted a process running on my Ubuntu that is taking 200% of the cpu resources.
It is belong to root, its name is kperl and is located in /temp
I have not been able to identify what is doing.
I also noted that in the same folder there is a file kperl.tar.gz

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8714712 Jun 23 19:58 kperl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3540510 Jul 25 15:17 kperl.tar.gz

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   1614 root      20   0  358200   9168   8472 S 194.1   0.1   3:48.17 kperl
```

I managed to kill the process and delete both files but after reboot it is still there and consuming resources.
I need help to understand what is about and eventually eliminate it forever. After killing it, nothing seems affected rather than better performance.
Any help will be appreciated. I have not found anything browsing "kperl".
Thanks

Comment: can you check `cron` to see if there is a cron job starting it at boot? or a systemd service? might be some kind of malware, especially if you didn't install it

Comment: also what is the `kperl` file? and what is inside the `.tar.gz`? can you look at the contents (or paste them here so we can see what the program is, assuming it's plaintext)?